# Как сделать цикл for с двумя параметрами проходящий по списку , выводящий произведение 2 чисел?

Tags: python, циклы, for

**Пример**:

```
A = [1, 3, 6, 8, 9,1]
```

**Вывод**:

```
3, 48, 9
```

КОД К ПРОБЛЕМЕ:

```
res_list1 = []
for x in range(0, len(numbers1) - 1):
    if type(numbers1[x]) == (type(int())):
        res1 = r10 * numbers1[x]
        res_list1.append(res1)
print(res_list1)
print(*(i * j for i, j in zip(res_list1[0::2], res_list1[1::2])))
```

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать? Какие возникли проблемы?

Comment: Что в `r10` и в `numbers1`?

Comment: numbers1 это все доступные числа в нашем случае от 1 до 60 , а r10 это вводимое число равное 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(*(i * j for i, j in zip(A[0::2], A[1::2])))
```

Comment: при большом количестве чисел(от 0 до 84) обработка происходит странно
0 54 180 378 648 990 1404 1890 2448 3078 3780 4554 5400 6318 7308 8370 9504 10710 11988 13338 14760 16254 17820 19458 21168 22950 24804 26730 28728 30798

Comment: я добавлю код в вопрос